# Visual Studio problem with C# double operation

Tags: c#, double

I am a noob trying to learn c#. I was following a turorial and all was fine till I tried to replicate a "double operation" that was on the video. The problem was with the results. I dont know why, after I added the two numbers, the result that should be a double, results in a int that iscompletely wrong. (its not just the lack of the "dot" the operation is done incorrectly).

[image: The Tutorial & Me Failing]

Am I such a dummy that I wrote the code incorrectly various times or is the Visual Studio lacking something? Can someone please help this noob here.

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code and make sure to [edit] the post to include necessary code, input, expected/actual output **as text** (not an image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is likely an issue with localisation. If you try entering 3,6 rather than 3.6 what do you get?

The system is treating it as 36, not 3.6

Comment: Hiiiiii

Thanks!!! It worked!! As a noob, now I am kind worried how much a little thing as a "dot" not work as supposed to be bc of languase setup. I had no idea that it was a thing, I need to keep an eye on that now.

That "error" let me down, I was like "goddammit, I am failing so early on". Now I can go back to the studies with relief. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, just remember converting string into an actual type is always going to be represented by the language which the system is on - in this case how decimals are formatted. Good luck on your journey and we all started knowing nothing :)